# Proved helpful OR Been proved helpful?

Tags: ielts

1. Cars have proved helpful to human beings.
2. Cars have been proved helpful to human beings.

**What are the differences between them?**

Comment: Exam questions/ homework questions may be OT.

Comment: I took it from https://ielts-academic.com/2015/12/11/ielts-writing-task-2-agree-or-disagree-question-sample-answer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to [Meriam Webster: *"prove"*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prove)

1. **"Cars have proved helpful to human beings"** follows the **intransitive** meaning of *prove*

   > "to turn out especially after trial or test "

   and presents the idea that at least up to now, cars have been and are considered useful to humans.

---

2. **"Cars have been proved helpful to human beings."** uses the passive voice construct of the **transitive** usage of *prove* meaning 3.b :

   > "to demonstrate as having a particular quality or worth"

   Taken literally this usage implies that "Someone out there ran a controlled scientific trial that demonstrated cars are helpful". This is a bit unlikely and requires some artistic license to present the idea conveyed by the first form.

Comment: Does "Cars have been proved helpful to human beings.", without "to be", equal "Cars have been proved **to be** helpful to human beings." please?

Comment: Yes they are equal.  There is no semantic difference between the two formulations.