# "it has proved" or "it has been proved"

Tags: grammar, past-perfect

I've a concern regarding the usage of been in the following case.

> It has proved that one of the main reasons for the rapid propagation
>   of false information is suspicious users.
>
> It has been proved that one of the main reasons for the rapid
>   propagation of false information is suspicious users.

Which sentence is correct and why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proved helpful OR Been proved helpful?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/472704/proved-helpful-or-been-proved-helpful) Also [“Prove that…” or simply “Prove…”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45551/prove-that-or-simply-prove)

Comment: I think that we would need to know the exact nature of the preceding sentence to determine which is appropriate to your situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase "it has been proved" means that something has been demonstrated to be true.

> It has been proved that one of the main reasons for the rapid propagation of false information is suspicious users.
>
> **prove**
>   **2** Demonstrate to be the specified thing by evidence or argument.
>   *if they are proved guilty we won't trade with them*

---

The phrase "it has proved" means the way something has become.

> I had wondered if the trip would be a failure, but it proved to be a success.
>
> **prove**
>   **2.1** Be seen or found to be.
>   *the scheme has proved a great success*

---

From the [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/prove) definitions.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant usages of the verb prove here are

> **prove** [verb]
>
> [transitive verb]
>
> 1a: to establish the existence, truth, or validity of (as by evidence
>   or logic)
>
> - prove a theorem
> - the charges were never proved in court
>
>   - [it was proved that smoking damages health]
>
> ...
>
> [intransitive verb]: to turn out especially after trial or test
>
> - the new drug proved effective

[[Merriam-Webster; amended](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prove)]

So the second sentence here, 'It has been proved that ...', a clefted version of say 'Research/ers have proved that ...', is obviously acceptable.

However, although the acceptability of

*It has turned out that that one of the main reasons for the rapid propagation of false information is suspicious users.*

would seem to validate the first sentence, it is at best awkward, difficult to parse, and in my opinion unidiomatic.